# Get posts associated with custom taxonomy alternate way

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type named `artwork` and I'm trying to get all of the artwork that is associated to the custom taxonomy of `artists` on the `taxonomy-artists.php` page.

I found an example [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-list-posts-that-share-the-current-posts-taxonomy-term) which works, but I'm wondering if I can trim it down a bit. I can't remember if I need to query the taxonomy term while on the taxonomy page. Seems like I don't need to if I am already on the specific page that has queried the custom taxonomy already. Here's the current code:

```
  <?php
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'artists' );
if($terms){
// post has course_type terms attached
$artists = array();
foreach ($terms as $term){
  $artists[] = $term->slug;
}

$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'artwork',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'artists',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $artists, //the taxonomy terms I'd like to dynamically query
      'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    ),
  ),
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC'
) );

$image = get_field('artwork_image');
$size = 'artwork-small';
$img = $image['sizes'][ $size ];

if ( have_posts() ): ?>
<ul>
  <?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
wp_reset_postdata();
} // end if($terms)
?>
```

Like I said, it works, but just think there might be some extra stuff in there that I don't need if I'm already on the specific custom taxonomy page of `taxonomy-artists.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you added in your question is for Displaying the other post that share the same TERM.

And I guess you want to display the all post for the current taxonomy not the single term ?

Then just used the default `$wp_query` to do it just remove the custom wp_query and keep the loop same.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to get all of the posts that are with the current taxonomy.

So something more like this?:
`<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'artwork');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
`

Comment: No just use the direct loop `<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

Comment: Ahhhhh, ok. DUH. Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for helping clear that up.